# Searchkick joins between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

Using searchkick gem how would I translate this to the .search way? Or is it not doable?

```
@projects = Project.joins(:proj_status)
```

Just wasn't sure how to do joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eager loading example from [gem reference](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#reference)

```
Product.search "milk", includes: [:brand, :stores]
```

for your code above

```
@projects = Product.search "milk", includes: [:proj_status]
```

Comment: Thanks. I get an error on this stating "unknown keywords: joins" I was using   @projects = Project.search "*", joins: [:proj_status]

Comment: it seems gems not provide joins, so I changed my answer to use includes ,see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for projects with status then you might need to do in the following way

in your project model where searchkick included try this

this is for indexing data
I assume Project has name and id and its associated model proj_status has a title.You may change the values depend on your model attributes

```
def search_data
   id: id,
   name: name,
   status: proj_status.title        
end
```

After Project.reindex

Then you can query Project model with status like,

```
@projects = Product.search "you query if any", includes: [:proj_status], where: {status: 'open'}
```